# Как установить Windows 10 рядом с Ubuntu

Tags: windows, install

Короче, при загрузке с флэшки ноут просто загружает Ubuntu, сама винда восстановиться не может из-за того что система стёрта с жёсткого диска и остался только Recovery Tool.

При запуске setup.exe из iso/флэшки файла через sudo wine пишет что нет autorun.dll и видимо из-за этого и сама флэшка не грузит установщик.
Как быть в такой ситуации?

Comment: Загружайтесь с iso/флэшки.

Comment: Как отвечать на такие комментарии адекватно я не знаю. При загрузке образа с ФЛЭШКИ вылезает UBUNTU, а не установщик

Comment: Это вполне нормальный комментарий... Вам действительно следует загрузится с флэшки. Отчего это может не получаться - другое дело. Следует убедится, что с загрузочной флешкой все в порядке, и, возможно, перезаписать ее заново использовав официальную программу installation media creation tool от Microsoft. Также следует убедится что в UEFI флэшка имеет более высокий приоритет при загрузке.